# Terraform starting EC2 sometimes stuck on "Still creating" until timeout

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I am running a terraform through Jenkins which starts up an ec2 then runs a shell script on it using user_data. I run this job 23 times in parallel, and for some reason each time only a few of them (anywhere from 1 to 8 and always different indices) will hang on "aws_instance.genomic-etl-ec2: Still creating..." until the connection times out after approximately an hour and throws a RequestExpired error, with no further details on why. The other instances start fine within around 2-3 minutes each.

My resource:

```
data "template_file" "my-user_data" {
  template = file("scripts/my_script.sh")
  
}

data "template_cloudinit_config" "my-user-data" {
  gzip          = true
  base64_encode = true

  # user_data
  part {
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    content      = data.template_file.my-user_data.rendered
  }

}

resource "aws_instance" "genomic-etl-ec2" {
  ami           = var.ami-id
  instance_type = "m5.12xlarge"

  associate_public_ip_address = true

  subnet_id = var.my-subnet-us-east-id

  iam_instance_profile = "my-deployment-profile"

  user_data = data.template_cloudinit_config.my-user-data.rendered

  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.my-sg1.id,
    aws_security_group.my-sg2.id
  ]
  root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = true
    encrypted             = true
    volume_size           = 1000
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sleep 40"
  }

  tags = {
    Owner       = "Me"
    Environment = "development"
    Name        = "My EC2 - ${id}"
    automaticPatches = "1"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes AWS instances take a long time to become fully available. It's not uncommon for those to take longer than Terraform's default timeout, causing Terraform to fail.

As per [the official documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance) on the Terraform `aws_instance` resource, the `create` timeout defaults to 10 minutes. If a particular instance type is taking longer than 10 minutes to become available, then you need to increase the `create` [timeout setting](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/syntax?_ga=2.17156665.1820500031.1667218853-656320854.1603562986#operation-timeouts):

```
resource "aws_instance" "genomic-etl-ec2" {
  # ...

  timeouts {
    create = "20m"
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is the case, would it still make attempts for a full hour before registering that it has timed out? Or is it getting hung up on something else and simply considering it all the "creating ec2" stage which enables the output?

Comment: As an update, I tried to increase the timeout time and there was not any effect